# How could i install OpenERP without Error?

Tags: installation, odoo

Please someone tell step by step to install OpenERP on Ubuntu. i have tried it but in results **Source Folder not found**. Please some one help me out.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your confusion my friend. There's a famous step-by-step guide in this link:

http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2011/04/how-to-install-openerp-6-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-server-part-1/

There's much work with this process but you may try following those steps on a virtual machine, and with every successful step you save the state of the virtual machine so that you can go back for a previous state if you make a mistake in the way. Good luck !